# Parsing data into a module-level mutable static variable

Tags: static, rust, mutability

I have a set of functions within a module that need access to some shared initialization-time state. Effectively I'd like to model this with a static mutable vector like:

```
static mut defs: Vec<String> = vec![];

fn initialize() {
    defs.push("One".to_string());
    defs.push("Two".to_string()); 
}
```

(Example: http://is.gd/TyNQVv, fails with "mutable statics are not allowed to have destructors".)

My question is similar to [Is it possible to use global variables in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605132/is-it-possible-to-use-global-variables-in-rust), but uses a `Vec` (i.e. a type with destructor), so the `Option`-based solution to that question doesn't seem to apply. Namely, this fails with the same error as my first attempt:

```
static mut defs: Option<Vec<String>> = None;

fn initialize() {
    let init_defs = vec![];
    init_defs.push("One".to_string());
    init_defs.push("Two".to_string()); 
    defs = Some(init_defs);
}
```

1. Is there a way to get access to a static ("global") vector that is populated at initialization time and visible at runtime?
2. Are there other patterns I should be considering to support this use case? Passing explicit references to the state vector is possible, but would clutter up a very large number of function signatures that all need access to this state.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`lazy_static`](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static) for this purpose:

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref defs: Vec<String> = {
        let mut init = vec!["One".to_string(), "Two".to_string()];
        // init.push(...); etc. etc.
        init
    }
}
```

That initialises a vector on the first access, and it is immutable after that. If you wish to modify it later, wrapping it in a `std::sync::Mutex` is a good first step.

> Are there other patterns I should be considering to support this use case? Passing explicit references to the state vector is possible, but would clutter up a very large number of function signatures that all need access to this state.

One pattern to consider is creating a context object that stores all the info the functions need, e.g.

```
struct Context {
    defs: Vec<String>
}
```

and then passing around `Context` ensures everyone knows what they need to know. You can even consider putting all/many/some of the functions as methods on `Context`, e.g.

```
impl Context {
    fn foo(&self) {
        if self.defs.len() > 10 {
             println!("lots of defs");
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

This pattern is especially good if you need to modify the context (automatically ensures thread safety), and/or if you wish to have several independent instances in a single process.

Comment: Thanks! This answers both of my questions very clearly. I especially like the Context struct pattern, with methods `impl`'d on. That feels more idiomatic.