# Change static string value

Tags: rust

I have an static mutable value:

```
static mut ADDRESS: &'static str = "";
```

It is global, not in any function.

And now i have a problem:
I have functions that read this value, them working correctly, but when i tried to make function that change this value from arguments - it start crying that value "does't live long enough".

```
#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern fn Java_Rust_setAddress(
    env: JNIEnv,
    _: JClass,
    address: JString
) {
    let input: String = env.get_string(address).expect("Couldn't get java string!").into();
    ADDRESS = &input /Error there/
}
```

What can i do with it? Transfering address in each case is not a variant, i really need a simple global variable.

```
ADDRESS = input.as_str()
```

not works too.

But

```
ADDRESS = "Something"
```

works good.

Comment: Your `String` will get dropped after your function is finished. A reference to it can't go in a static variable with a static lifetime.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a global, mutable singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791532/how-do-i-create-a-global-mutable-singleton)

Comment: @Aplet123 it's not critical for me make ADDRESS value from variable or from variable value. I can't believe that programming language made in 2010 and with so big community don't have so simple functionality as i need.

Comment: The problem is that static mutable data are not simple.

Answer (score 2):

Your `String` will get dropped after the function is finished. Therefore, you cannot store a reference to in a `static` variable:

```rust
ADDRESS = &input;
       // ^^^^^^ input does not live long enough
       // ADDRESS requires that `input` is borrowed for `'static`
}
// < `input` dropped here while still borrowed by ADDRESS
```

Instead, you need to store a global heap-allocated `String`. There are a couple ways to have a global heap-allocated variable [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605132/is-it-possible-to-use-global-variables-in-rust). In your case, you can use a `thread_local` global `static` variable and wrap the string in a `Cell`, which provides mutability:

```rust
use std::cell::Cell;

thread_local!(static ADDRESS: Cell<String> = Cell::new("".to_string()));

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern fn Java_Rust_setAddress(
    env: JNIEnv,
    _: JClass,
    address: JString
) {
    let input: String = env.get_string(address).expect("Couldn't get java string!").into();
    ADDRESS.with(|address| address.set(input));
}
```